# how to remove part of shadow in custom painter

Tags: flutter

I draw this rectangle :

```
class RectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint fillPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.deepPurpleAccent
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = size.width * 0.00
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;

    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width * 0.1490000, size.height * -0.0020000);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.1510000, size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.6510000, size.height * 0.5020000);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.1490000, size.height * -0.0020000);
    path_0.close();

    Paint shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3)
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcATop
      ..imageFilter = ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 0, sigmaY: 10);
    ;
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, fillPaint);
  }
```

this is result:

[image]

and my usage:

```
  Positioned(
    top: 60,
    left: 135,
    child: CustomPaint(
      size: const Size(80, 80),
      painter: RectanglePainter(),
    ),
  ),
```

I just want to remove this line :

[image]

how can I do ?

Comment: use `maskFilter`, not `imageFilter`

Comment: If I use maskFilter how can I change shadow offset ? @pskink

Comment: check how `ShapeDecorstion` is doing that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e1e47221e8/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/shape_decoration.dart#L348